# Relating the inverse Gram matrix of ${v_1, ..., v_k}$ to that of $\{v_1, ..., v_{(k-1)} \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider a set of vectors $S = \{u_1, \dots, u_k\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. (I'm generally interested in scenarios when $k << n$, not sure how much this matters.)

Let $G_k$ denote the Gram matrix of the vectors in $S$, and let $G_{(k-1)}$ denote the Gram matrix of the vectors $S\setminus\{u_k\}$. Is there a way to relate $G_k^{-1}$ to $G_{(k-1)}^{-1}$ in any way? I notice that for the family of vectors I'm considering the topleft $(k-1) \times (k-1)$ block of $G_{k}^{-1}$ [is numerically close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gcIu.jpg) to $G_{(k-1)}^{-1}$. Is there a way to quantify this closeness?

Comment: Technical term "augmented matrix". See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1391231/305862)

Comment: I doubt the numerical closedness. For example Let $0<a<1$ and $$G_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a\\ a&1\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $$G_2^{-1}= {1\over 1-a^2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -a\\ -a&1\end{pmatrix}$$ The quantities $1$ and $(1-a^2)^{-1}$ are far apart if $ a\to 1^-.$